# net eth0: rx->offset 4294967295

Tags: networking, debian

Is this anything important? Where is it coming from?

I'm running Debian Squeeze (6) and keep seeing this in dmesg/messages and so on...

```
[20471825.303351] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.313899] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.342809] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.371154] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.401408] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.406837] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.434638] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.464767] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.490857] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
[20471825.498196] net eth0: rx->offset: 0, size: 4294967295
```

**ifconfig output for eth0**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:46:2e:77:8f:d7  
      inet addr:36.239.27.153  Bcast:46.249.37.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::809f:5468/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::a49:390f/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::efbd:618a/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fe57:8fd7/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::8378:23f2/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::c4c0:8a96/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::5a87:8650/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::4e12:91e4/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::1d2f:9e6c/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::dc71:8af6/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a00:1ca8:e:4::6ec:db3c/48 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2917413 errors:495 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:13718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:977859566 (932.5 MiB)  TX bytes:16632912 (15.8 MiB)
      Interrupt:9
```

Comment: Please edit your post and append the output of `ifconfig eth0`?

Comment: @quanta done, need anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Xen-devel mailing list](http://markmail.org/thread/tmuhd2c4a7hxx2lp#query:+page:1+mid:tmuhd2c4a7hxx2lp+state:results), try to disable [TCP Segmentation Offload](http://kerneltrap.org/node/397) on `eth0` with:

```
ethtool -K eth0 tso off
```

to see if this messages go away.

Comment: you got a point, you find solution and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

The message comes from the module linux/drivers/net/xen_netfront.c:

```
dev_warn(dev, "rx->offset: %x, size: %u\n", rx->offset, rx->status);
```

In the if() above it checks `rx->status < 0` and obviously it's < 0 (or unsigned 4294967295). It then does `xennet_move_rx_slot()`, whatever that means.